Why is it that calling standard sum on a numpy array produces a different result than numpy.sum?
Observe in the following code, creating an numpy array and calling the builtin python sum function produces different results than numpy.sum
How is numpy's sum function implemented? And why is the result different?
test = [.1]*10
test = [np.float64(x) for x in test]
test[5]= np.float64(-.9)

d = [np.asarray(test) for x in range(0,60000)]
sum(sum(d))

outputs
np.float64(-1.7473212210461497e-08)

but
np.sum(d)

outputs
np.float64(9.987344284922983e-12)


dupe? Is floating-point math broken?

np.sum(np.sum(d, axis=0)) will give the same result as sum(sum(d)), within a small margin of error, so it's just a boring axis/float inaccuracy thing.

@wim They give more similar but not the same result.

This question is similar to: Is floating-point math broken?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As per first comment, if you are surpised results are different, you should also likely be surprised neither are exactly 0?

It's due to the summation order. If you add up all the 0.1's first, you get a large intermediate result, giving higher inaccuracy of the end result. If you go row-wise (9x 0.1, 1x -0.9), the intermediate result stays closer to 0, preserving accuracy up to the end. (edit -... posted as answer..)

Not a dupe imho; the other question explains why the result is inexact, but not why there are two different results from (apparently) the same operation.

The other error is because python's sum is reduce sum, and numpy's sum is pairwise sum. Try sum([np.float64(1)] + [np.float64(1e-16)]*10).

Look at math.fsum, https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html

@Liam385 Ok, similar.  The point is, how many Q&A do we need on this site about floating point inaccuracies, it's not very interesting.

All duplicate questions are boring. All non-duplicate questions are interesting. People should try to avoid asking duplicate questions. But if there is a topic that you find boring, it is you who should avoid it.

question is not necessarily about fp innaccuracy we all understand that. Its about numpy implementation of summation.
@ken had the answer I was looking for it seems that numpy uses pairwise summation which I was not familiar with

We want answers in the dedicated "answer" place. Having an answer inside the question is confusing; we don't do that here. I removed it; see below if you need answer(s).

Numpy uses pairwise summation:https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3685 but python uses reduce summation.
The answer is only partially related to FP inaccuracy because if I have an array of FP numbers and use the same algorithm to sum them, I should expect the same result if I sum them in the same order.

It's due to the summation order. If you add up all the 0.1's first, you get a large intermediate result, giving higher inaccuracy of the end result. If you go row-wise (9x 0.1, 1x -0.9), the intermediate result stays closer to 0, preserving accuracy up to the end.
More variants:
>>> np.sum(np.sum(arr, axis=0)) # column-wise iteration
-1.747685018926859e-08
>>> np.sum(np.sum(arr, axis=1)) # row-wise iteration, more accurate
-3.3306690738754696e-12
>>> np.sum(arr)
9.987344284922983e-12
>>> sum(sum(arr))
-1.7473212210461497e-08

Some more theory:

In "e" notation, the last significant digit of a float64 is about 16 "less" than the first one.
When summing numbers, the precision "loss" can be estimated as the number of summands (~6e5 here).
going rowwise gives you intermediate results in the range 1e0. Precision is 1e-16. Summation costs ~5 digits: 16-5 = 11 => result is 0 +- 1e-11.
going columnwise, you end up with intermediate result .1 * 5 * 6e4 = 3e4. Last significant digit is then ~1e-12. The error probably comes mainly from substracting all the .9s, which are 6e4 summands -> loses roughly 4 more digits => result is 0 +- 1e-8. (Actually a little bit more).


Why does np.sum(np.sum(arr, axis=0)) and sum(sum(arr)) not produce the same result though? Arent they adding along the same axes in the same order?
The point of the question again is why do these function calls which should logically be the same produce different results

Good question. Might be that numpy uses additional tricks (see the other answer) instead of going through the numbers one by one.

here's numpy's actual summation, if you're curious. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/_core/src/umath/loops_utils.h.src#L81
